# Geometry, sets, and simple closed paths

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory, euclidean-geometry, curves

I've been trying to find a way to define a simple polygon with sets of points and segments. I have some questions about this, but I need to introduce a few things first.

Let $n\in\{3,4,\dots\}$ be some finite constant, and $I=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Then let $p_i\in\Bbb R^2$ for all $i\in I$. Assume that $\forall i,j\in I, p_i\neq p_j\iff i\neq j$. Then let $p=\{p_i:i\in I\}$. Finally, assume that there is no line $l$, where $p\subset l$.

Then, we define, for $a,b\in\Bbb R^2$, a segment function $$s(a,b)=\{a+t(b-a):t\in[0,1]\}$$
With this, we define, for any $i,j\in I$, $$s_{ij}=s(p_i,p_j)$$
Then we define $$\phi=\{s_{ij}:(i,j)\in I\times I\}$$
Therefore, $$p\subset\phi$$

**My question:**

How do we rigorously define the closed, simple path made out of segments, $\gamma\subseteq\phi$, where $p\subset\gamma$?

**Update:** I found an answer! Check out my answer below.

**Update 2.0:** I didn't actually find an answer! But this is how far I've come:

First of all, it is incorrect that $p\subset\phi$, because $p\neq\{\{p_i\}:i\in I\}$. I had noticed that $\{\{p_i\}:i\in I\}\subset\phi$, because $\{\{p_i\}:i\in I\}=\{s_{ii}:i\in I\}\subset\phi$. Therefore $p\cap\phi=\emptyset$.

Next, I noticed that, if we define $$\Phi=\phi\setminus\{\{p_i\}:i\in I\}$$
and we draw out some diagrams of $\Phi$, we notice something interesting. If $A\in\Phi$, and $A$ intersects any other segments in $\Phi$, then $A\not\in\gamma$. The remaining task is to find a set $G\subseteq\Phi$ where all elements of $G$ do not intersect any elements of $\Phi$ except for themselves. A possible definition: $$G=\{A\in\Phi:\forall B\in\Phi, (A\cap B)\in\{A,\emptyset\}\}$$
Where $\emptyset=\{\}$ is the empty set (for clarification).

In any case, given the definition (that I gave in words) for $G$, $$\gamma=G\cup p$$

Comment: p is not a subset of $\phi$. p is a set of points. $\phi$ is a set of line segments. p is not even the subset of any of the segments in $\phi$, because p is not in any line.

Comment: If you want to make an n-gon, you need to specify that $p_{i-1}$, $p_i$, and $p_{i+1}$ are not colinear. If you use all the segments in $\phi$ you won't get a polygon. You'll get $K_n$, the complete graph on n vertices.

Comment: $\cup${$s_{1,2}$, $s_{2,3}$, ... $s_{n-1,n}$, $s_{n,1}$} will get you a polygon, but it won't necessarily be simple. The key is in numbering the p's to avoid edges crossing. Unfortunately, I have no bright ideas about that at the moment.

Comment: @SteveB $p\subset\phi$ because I did not specify that $i\neq j$ in the definition of $\phi$. Here's another definition of $p$: $$p=\{s_{ii}:i\in I\}$$

Comment: @SteveB I agree with all your other comments though. Tell me if you get any good ideas.

Comment: @SteveB wait nevermind. $$p\neq\{\{p_i\}:i\in I\}$$ See my answer below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84732/discussion-between-clathratus-and-steve-b).